# How to make M1015 ServerRaid card happy so it doesn't halt system boot?

Tags: storcli

Long story short, 
I have a brand new "IBM Serveraid M1015 SAS/SATA Controller", I plug it in to allow even more hard drives plugged into this machine and I get:

> ```
> All the disks from your previous configuration are gone. If this is
> an unexpected message, then please power off your system and check your cables
> to ensure all disks are present.
> Press any key to continue, or 'C' to load the configuration utillity.
> ```

I have gotten `storcli64`, but card "doesn't support" JBOD mode when asked to turn it on via storcli, but when clearing the boot blocking message by hand all the drives work correctly.

I need to know what to tell the ServeRAID card, preferably via `storcli64`, to make it happy and clear the system for booting without nuking the data on the drives.

My alternative is moving a keyboard and display every time that machine is rebooted for security upgrades, which makes me grumpy, and I dont really consider it acceptable behavior for the system to refuse to boot without human input in its default configuration.

P.S. I've come across folks recommend a HBA instead, I will try that next time because this card was supposed to fulfill for me the job of connecting disks, not manage the data on them.

Comment: Gonna leave these here for my future self to read:
https://www.servethehome.com/ibm-serveraid-m1015-part-4/